# How to repeat local notification every 5 sec in background

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, local

Hi I want to show a notification for a call like WhatsApp
I tried to make it via Timer but it didn't work

```
self.timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
DispatchQueue.main.async {                       
   self.scheduleLocalNotification(nameLocatino: myString)                                
}})
```

Comment: What is the purpose of a local notification firing that frequently?

Comment: @MartinR i receive VoIP call

Comment: @dagdk still one should not fire multiple notifications for one event

Comment: Basically you are using the wrong API, the appropriate one is `scheduledTimer(timeInterval...`

Comment: @vadian still don't work(

Comment: Did you think about using CallKit?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

Comment: This is the wrong approach, and can't be implemented this way. Receiving VoIP calls is handled through PushKit since iOS 8: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html. See also https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1938/_index.html about the deprecation in iOS 10 of the legacy VoIP system that maintained a persistent network connection.

Comment: @IMike17 in my app communication proceeds with custom UI) but thank you, didn't know about CallKit

Comment: @RobNapier yea im using PushKit) I just was wondering how to repeat notifications) thank you for "Voice Over IP (VoIP) Best Practices" reference its very usefull)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use NSCalendarNotifiationTrigger

Example for you

```
      var date = Date()
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    for i in 0...10 {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Title\(i)"
    content.body = "Body"
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current
    let secondsToAdd = 5
    dateComponents.second = secondsToAdd
    guard let futureDate = dateComponents.calendar?.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: date),
        let futureDateComponents = dateComponents.calendar?.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: futureDate) else { return }
        date = futureDate
    print(futureDate)
    // Create the trigger as a repeating event.
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
        dateMatching: futureDateComponents, repeats: false)
    // Create the request
    let notificationIdentifier = "notification\(i)seconds" // you can use this indentifier if you want to cancel a notification
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationIdentifier,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)
    // Schedule the request with the system.
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            // Handle any errors.
        }
    }
}
```

where secondsToAdd is 5 so it calculates the upcoming date
Above code will post 10 notification in 5 second interval
You need to calculate the maximum time (last date entry) and schedule notification using the above code

Comment: This will pop up a notification message every 5 seconds that the user must tap in order to re-launch the app. It won't re-launch the app automatically every 5 seconds. (Nothing will do that.) While the title doesn't make it clear, the OP is requesting something that would allow their app to receive VoIP calls "like WhatsApp," not pop up a message every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thats the complete different question than the one requested.
To receive WhatsApp like VoIP calls you need to use Pushkit.